# Fundamental Group of a Hexagon with Edge Identifications

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

[image: X=Hexagon w/ Identifications]

What's the easiest way to compute this thing's fundamental group?

I've been playing with it for a little while, and I'm getting $\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z}$. After making the ID's I think the 1-cells are homotopic to wedge sum of two circles and we have a 2-cell attached via the map $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$?

Comment: It looks like it is a wedge sum of 3 circles with attachment map $abca^{-1}b^{-1}c^{-1}$

Comment: It is the torus. Do you know what the fundamental group of the torus is?

Comment: @Gaffney: you are assuming that all six vertices of the hexagon are identified to a single point, but that is not the case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a torus as you can easily see from this picture:
[image]

Hence $\pi_{1}=\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Great diagrams. Thank you.